# Get Navigation bar height in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, navigationbar

I am working on a project where i need to get the navigation bar height.I am getting the whole screen height using:

```
Helpers.ApplicationContext.ScreenHeight = (int)Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
Helpers.ApplicationContext.ScreenWidth = (int)Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
```

But I am not able to get the navigation bar height.

Can any one please suggest an idea to get the navigation bar height of my page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS This may help you :

```
var navbarHeight = YourViewControllerInstance.NavigationController?.NavigationBar.Frame.Height;
```

For Android :

```
TypedArray styledAttributes = this.Theme.ObtainStyledAttributes(
new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.ActionBarSize });
var actionbarHeight = (int) styledAttributes.GetDimension(0, 0);
styledAttributes.recycle();
```

Above example gives Height in Pixel. Please find more refined sample as below which provide height in Pixel as well as DP:

```
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
int actionBarHeightInPixel = 0;
int actionBarHeightInDP = 0;
DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;

if (Theme.ResolveAttribute(Resource.Attribute.actionBarSize, tv, true))
{
    actionBarHeightInPixel = TypedValue.ComplexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.Data, metrics);
    actionBarHeightInDP = actionBarHeightInPixel / (int)metrics.Density;
}
```

Comment: Hi Milan, I am trying your code getting navigation bar height in both android and ios , in Ios it work's great but in android I am getting very huge value, that's are wrong value or my some other value. I am getting above 200 in android.

Comment: Deepak, I have updated my answer. Please give it a try and let me know if it solves your problem.